# const scoping issue within a switch statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have the following code in my reducer. In both cases, findFile() returns a result, however, only in the first occurrence (setImageRotation) will "origFile" get set. Changing the name of the second occurrence of "origFile" will allow it to get set. I'm wondering why this is case, as const has a block level scope.

```
    function handler(stateArg, action) {
        const state = stateArg || {};
        let nextState;

        switch (action.type) {
            case actions.types.setImageRotation: {
                const origFile = findFile(action.fileUid, state.files);
                const newfile = Object.assign({}, origFile, { rotation: action.rotation });
                nextState = updateStateFile(state, newfile);
                break;
            }

            case actions.types.setImageRegionOfInterest: {
                const origFile = findFile(action.fileUid, state.files);
                const newfile = Object.assign({}, origFile, { roi: action.roi });
                nextState = updateStateFile(state, newfile);
                break;
            }
        }
        return nextState || state;
    }
```

Notes:

- origFile is not defined anywhere else in my solution.
- there are no console errors

Transpiled Code:

```
        case actions.types.setImageRegionOfInterest:{
            var origFile = findFile(action.fileUid, state.files);
            var newfile = (0, _assign2.default)({}, origFile, { roi: action.roi });
            nextState = updateStateFile(state, newfile);
            break;
        }

        case actions.types.setImageRotation:{
            var _origFile = findFile(action.fileUid, state.files);
            var _newfile = (0, _assign2.default)({}, _origFile, { rotation: action.rotation });
            nextState = updateStateFile(state, _newfile);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people stated in the discussion, this code works. What I ran into was a bug with Google Chromes debugger & source mapping. When I turned source mapping off and debugged the transpiled code, I got the correct value for "origfile".